# How to create a sphere with a web on it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

[image: it concerns the sphere web part]

I am trying to recreate this sphere with webbing on it in Illustrator. I tried a lot of things but I can't get the same outcome. I think I am overthinking it but I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone point me in the right direction or tools to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it looks like a 3d effect, let's apply that effect.

Make your logo a Symbol. We will use it later.

Draw a circle and cut it half. It will be used to make a ball.

Select the semi-circle and go to **Menu>>Effect>>3D>>Revolve**.

Use the setting of the attached image...

Click the **Map Art...** button and load the symbol.

With some more tweaking, you can get the desired look.

See the image below for values used:

[image]

Comment: LeoNas, thank you so much for your help. I was actually on the good path with the 3d revolve, my error was dat the webbing as a symbol was drawn wrong by me resulting in a wrong result. So thanks you where a live saver.

Comment: Leonas, i have a strange problem. i added 2 exports of the logo. the one with gradients shows more pixelated. i can't seem to fix that. could you advise me on this?
without gradient: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDP6r.png with gradient:https://i.stack.imgur.com/baiP8.png

Comment: I think this is as Illustrator issue. Try to load it in Photoshop and export it.

Comment: If this answer worked fine, Mark it as the right answer. Good luck.

Comment: I have exported of as svg and then saved of as PNG problem gone. Thanks for your help and efforts